# Implement git branch --contains with rugged library

Tags: ruby, git, branch, rugged

I'm working with a ruby script that execute the following git command on a given git repository.

```rb
  branches = `git branch -a --contains #{tag_name}`
```

This approach has some drawbacks with command output (that may change in different git versions) and is subject to git binary version on the hosting machine, so I was trying to see if it's possible to replace that command using [rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) but I wasn't able to find anything similar to that.

Maybe in rugged there's no way to implement `--contains` flag, but I think it should be pretty easy to implement this behavior:

Given any git *commit-ish* (a tag, a commit sha, etc.) how to get (with rugged) the list of branches (both local and remote) that contains that commit-ish?

I need to implement something like github commit show page, i.e. `tag xyz is contained in master, develop, branch_xx`

Comment: want to exactly this thing. Did you ever figure this out??

Comment: @quinn yes I did it, here's the code: https://github.com/uala/drone-rancher-deploy/blob/master/lib/rancher_deployer/tag_checker.rb#L33-L45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved with [this code](https://github.com/uala/drone-rancher-deploy/blob/master/lib/rancher_deployer/tag_checker.rb#L33-L45):

```
def branches_for_tag(tag_name, repo_path = Dir.pwd)
  @branches ||= begin
    repo = Rugged::Repository.new(repo_path)
    # Convert tag to sha1 if matching tag found
    full_sha = repo.tags[tag_name] ? repo.tags[tag_name].target_id : tag_name
    logger.debug "Inspecting repo at #{repo.path}, branches are #{repo.branches.map(&:name)}"
    # descendant_of? does not return true for it self, i.e. repo.descendant_of?(x, x) will return false for every commit
    # @see https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/4362
    repo.branches.select { |branch| repo.descendant_of?(branch.target_id, full_sha) || full_sha == branch.target_id }
  end
end
```